# RequireJS plugins and relative paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I've written a plugin for requirejs that pulls code over a websocket.

It works great!  The problem is, when code is loaded over the socket, it may refer to other code that needs to be loaded from the websocket.

So, for instance, the first call may be:

```
//defining library.js
define( [ './some/other/resource' ],
        function(resource) {
                //do stuff with resource here
        }
);

//defining caller
define( [ 'websocket!namespace:path/to/library.js' ],
        function(library) {
                //do stuff with library here
        }
);
```

But if library.js require()s something that it needs, I need to prefix all requests from that library with:

```
'websocket!namespace:'
```

The above code will cause a request at

```
'namespace:path/to/some/other/resource'
```

I've been trying to add the plugin prefix in config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'namespace': 'websocket!namespace'
    }
});
```

But it seems like when requests from the library are normalized, they don't refer to the path config, I think, or that plugins have been stripped at that point.

How can I set the config so all requests to namespace include the plugin, or how do I keep the plugin prefix for subsequent requests from library?